# PHP Session encoding

Tags: php, session

I have a problem. I am writing a shop cms.
When you add an item to cart, in a session recorded data of item, such as color, size, etc.
And then this data is output in a cart, but there data is in the wrong encoding.

How to set the encoding of the data contained in the sessions?

On the local server it is good, but in the cloud i have encoding problem.

Comment: Session has no encoding, the problem lies either in database encoding or whole output.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Perhaps it would be more accurate to say that the (standard/default) session handler does not *change* the encoding - there is no such thing as text which is in no encoding.